# Mi trigger no funciona

Tags: django, postgresql

tengo un problema con un trigger en postgresql, su funcion es realizar un update sobre un campo de la misma tabla en la que inserto, pues ese campo puede tener diferentes valores, entiendase que ese campo es una nomenclatura de un documento, puede ser inscripcion, licencia, x, para ello utilizo unas sequencias para cada tipo de documento.

resulta que el trigger no actualiza el campo, utilizo django y postgresql.

aca dejo el codigo

```
set search_path=funciones_vistas;
create or replace function nro_tramite() returns trigger as $$
declare
siglas_tramite varchar;
begin
    siglas_tramite := siglas from tools.tipo_tramite where id = new.tipo_tramite_id;
    if siglas_tramite = 'IU' then
        new.nro_tramite := 'SDLC-'||siglas_tramite||'-'||lpad(nextval('"funciones_vistas".inscripcion')::text,5,'0');
        return new;
    elsif siglas_tramite = 'LCA' then
        new.nro_tramite := 'SDLC-'||siglas_tramite||'-'||lpad(nextval('"funciones_vistas".licencia_ca')::text,5,'0');
        return new;
    elsif siglas_tramite = 'LCO' then
        new.nro_tramite := 'SDLC-'||siglas_tramite||'-'||lpad(nextval('"funciones_vistas".licencia_co')::text,5,'0');
        return new;
    elsif siglas_tramite = 'LTM' then
        new.nro_tramite := 'SDLC-'||siglas_tramite||'-'||lpad(nextval('"funciones_vistas".licencia_tlm')::text,5,'0');
        return new;
    elsif siglas_tramite = 'LOP' then
        new.nro_tramite := 'SDLC-'||siglas_tramite||'-'||lpad(nextval('"funciones_vistas".licencia_op')::text,5,'0');
        return new;
    elsif siglas_tramite = 'REN' then
        new.nro_tramite := 'SDLC-'||siglas_tramite||'-'||lpad(nextval('"funciones_vistas".renovacion')::text,5,'0');
        return new;
    elsif siglas_tramite = 'APT' then
        new.nro_tramite := 'SDLC-'||siglas_tramite||'-'||lpad(nextval('"funciones_vistas".aportes')::text,5,'0');
        return new;
    end if;
end;
$$
language 'plpgsql';

create trigger nro_tramite after insert on recaudacion.tramite for each row execute procedure nro_tramite();
```

Comment: Deberías probar poniendo en lugar de asignar en new.nro_tramite poner un update  recaudacion.tramite where ID= new tipo_tramite_id

Comment: Creo que el trigger debería lanzarse antes (before) del insert no después (after)

Comment: Gracias por los aportes, sucede que he probado de ambas maneras en que me han sugerido dentro de la app donde debe funcionar y no ejecuta, lo inicie en otra bd y funciona, no entiendo, reiniciare el servidor de base de datos a ver